# How to increase the no of seconds pjsip rings?

Tags: pjsip

Currently, without any code changes, PJSIP rings (after issuing 180 sip code) for about 15 seconds or so before call is dropped. Can I increase this time to 60 seconds? Is there such flexibility in PJSIP?

Comment: Are you sure that it's PjSIP which is dropping the call. It could be your server dropping it after call timeout.

Comment: Good point. Will try as suggested.

Comment: @nnb: Actually, I am trying to set it at 120 sec on Freeswitch server but it is taking only the default value. The variable I used was call_timeout